# Number of Legal Previous Moves in the Game of Life

Tags: algorithm, conways-game-of-life

Given the current tick of the game in Conway's game of life (or any other cellular automation game), how can one find the number of legal previous ticks that could have been evaluated into the tick provided?

For example, assuming the game of life can be represented as:

```
0 0 0 0 0 ...
X 0 X 0 0 ...
0 X 0 0 0 ...
0 0 0 0 X ...
...
```

where `X` is "alive/on/true" and `0` is "dead/off/false", or more simply as a `boolean[][]`, how can one work out the following:

```
public static int numberOfValidPreviousTicks(boolean[][] current) {
    return -1; // return answer
}
```

It is clear that one could find *every* possible previous game state from the grid size and determine if that would evaluate into the current state using the normal rules.

However, there must be some obvious ways to speed up this process so that it is not `O(2^n)` (where n is the total number of cells in the grid).

Caching of course could help in places but where exactly would it fit in?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton)

Comment: I would guess that this problem is NP-Complete. Life is Turing-complete, so a rewind algorithm feels awfully close to finding inputs that make a program return true. See if you can find a reduction to 3-SAT, or something along those lines.

Comment: @CraigGidney: I think you're right.  I would expect that as with many NP-Complete problems, most "random" sets of inputs would be amenable to polynomial-time solutions, but unless P=NP, no polynomial-time approach will work for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

For an `m*m` board, you can do it in `O(m*8^m)` with dynamic programming.

The idea is to start at the top of the board and work down, calculating for each pair of rows for the `i-1, i`'th position all of the rows that can be in the `i+1`'th position to give the right `i`'th row of output.

That's better than `2^O(n) = 2^(O(m*m))` but is pretty slow.

I don't think that you'll do much better than that.